# How to go from $n>\delta \implies \left| \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) - \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)\right|<\epsilon$ to limit at infinity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a\,..b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g:[a\,..b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable functions.

We have the result $\forall \epsilon\in\mathbb R_{>0}:  \exists \delta \in \mathbb R_{>0}:\forall n>\delta:\bigg|\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) - \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i) \,\bigg|<\epsilon$

How can it be now proved that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i)$?

EDIT: The question I'm asking is related to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Definition_for_a_smooth_curve) Wikipedia article on arc length.

Comment: 1) why is $\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$, if $n$ is constrained to be a natural number? 2) is it necessary that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable? 3) when you write $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_i)$, where's your $n$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt I'm asking this question in reference to a particular proof I'm reading that uses this result, and I got to this point with a real $\delta$ and natural $n$. I don't know if it's needed, but once again, this is done to aid me in going through a proof which considers differentiable functions, and since I have no clue what to do I prefer to write this property down, in case this might be important. I corrected the error with lack of $n$.

Comment: And what are the $x_i?$ Any $n$ points at all?

Comment: @zhw. In the original question $[a\,..b]$ is subdivided into them, although I don't think this is particularly important.

Comment: Do they form a partition of $[a,b]?$? If so, say so. We don't have the original question in front of us.

Comment: @zhw. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Definition_for_a_smooth_curve Here is what I'm referring to.

Comment: Suppose $f,g$ are both the constant $1.$ Then the difference in sums is always $0.$ But the other limits are $\infty.$